How to add pkgs.org and other mirrors in centOS 8?
https://centos.pkgs.org/8-stream/centos-appstream-x86_64/
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/

I am new to centOS. I want to add these two repositories so that whenver I use yum install I get the latest packages from them.
For example I want to install clang 17.
Currently when I input yum install clang
It shows clang 12 which is pretty outdated.
I want the result like
When I input
sudo yum install clang it shows the clang version 17

Edit the file /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, then add those repos to your list:
"mirrorlist=example.com/...",
"mirrorlist=example2.com/...",

